How do you count repeating entries in a column?
I have a data frame like this:



Value




0


0


0


1


1


0


0



I would like to create another column such that it counts the number of time a value repeats in a batch:



Value
Freq




0
3


0
3


0
3


1
2


1
2


0
1



Group by will not work here.
How would you do it?

df['freq'] = df.groupby('Value')['Value'].transform('size')

@QuangHoang thats incorrect

Your output is not aligned with the input, is it? The input has a 2 zeros at the end. Anyway, should be df.groupby(df['Value'].ne(df['Value'].shift()).cumsum()).transform('size'), I think

try df.groupby([df['Value'].ne(df['Value'].shift()).cumsum()]).transform('count')

Here's one approach:

Distinguish between groups by checking Series.ne against the shifted version of 'Value' (Series.shift) and apply Series.cumsum.
Pass the result to df.groupby and get 'size' inside groupby.transform:

import pandas as pd

data = {'Value': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 0}} # deleting the last `0`
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['Freq'] = (
    df.groupby(df['Value'].ne(df['Value'].shift()).cumsum())['Value']
    .transform('size')
)

Output
   Value  Freq
0      0     3
1      0     3
2      0     3
3      1     2
4      1     2
5      0     1

